# CosmosDB: Unable to run group by query in python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to run a group by query in Azure CosmosDB using Python SDK.
I've set **enable_cross_partition_query=True** in the container client settings

```
{"errors":["Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggregateFunc>' for aggregates"]}
```

I have multiple aggregates in my query. Below is my sample query

```
select count(col1) as alias1, sum(col2) as alias2......from container group by col1
```

Nothing is working.... Please help if there are any alternatives to do this

Answer (score 3):

Python SDK for Azure Cosmos DB does not have the support for GROUP BY operations,

You can read it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/cosmos/azure-cosmos#data-plane-limitations) under the limitations.

Comment: fyi this really should be a comment. The question isn't a programming question (there is no code provided), more of a documentation issue (and should be closed)